# Backface visibility disabling form controls

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, css-transforms

I've been working on a project where I have to develop a web page that looks like this

http://cdpn.io/jkCqI

Though it works fine with FireFox, the only issue that I am facing is that the form controls for this webpage do not work in Google Chrome. I suspect it is an issue of

```
   backface-visibility
```

or anything like that.
Can anyone please help me with this? How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common problem in Chrome, and the equivalent of z-index positioning in 3D, the z transform.

Try

```
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);  // added translateZ 
}
```

and it will work